# Why scheduling local notifications for daily schedule not working in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, uilocalnotification

> Im trying to set a daily notification on my app using local notifications package on flutter but its not working(every other notifications options are working like afterseconds, notifications now),i have done all the required changes in manifest file.

here's the link to my manifest file: https://pastebin.com/thEJShSB
and here's the function i am using:

```
 Future<void> _showDailyAtTime() async {
    var time = Time(9, 0, 0);
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'repeatDailyAtTime channel id',
        'repeatDailyAtTime channel name',
        'repeatDailyAtTime description');
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showDailyAtTime(
        0,
        'show daily title',
        'Daily notification shown at approximat',
        time,
        platformChannelSpecifics);
  }
```

> Im calling this function on tap like this:

```
ListTile(
        title: Text('About',style: TextStyle(fontSize:18,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
        onTap: () {
          // Update the state of the app.
          // ...
          
          _showDailyAtTime();
        },
      )
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I have the same problem